# scala how to drop lines from df based on the column value

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

i have Data frame with these values i need to filtered min date (groupby( id,count) and summary should change as equal to more

```
id secid count date   summary
1   2     9    20170608  equal
1   3     9    20160608  equal
2   3     8    20170608  less
3   3     9    20160608  equal
```

I need to show

```
id secid count date   summary
1   2     9    20170608  more
2   3     8    20170608  less
3   3     9    20160608  equal
```

Comment: what do you mean with Df?

Comment: i have Data frame with above values i need to filtered min date (groupby( id,count) and summary should change as equal to more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupBy` to group `id` and `count` together and then use `when` and `otherwise` to change your summary field to `more` in case you have more `date` for the same `id` and `count`.

```
//create your original DF
val df = Seq((1, 2, 9, 20170608, "equal"),
      (1, 3, 9, 20160608, "equal"),
      (2, 3, 8, 20170608, "less"),
      (3, 3, 9, 20160608, "equal"),
      (1, 2, 8, 20170608, "random"),
      (1, 2, 8, 20170608, "random"))
      .toDF("id", "secid", "count", "date", "summary")

//Create a UDF to find the length of datelist after grouping
val isMoreThanOne = udf((lst: Seq[Int], summary: String) => lst.size > 1 && summary.equals("equal"))

//apply groupby and other operations to get the result
df.groupBy("id", "count")
  .agg(collect_list("date").as("datelist"),
    max("date").as("date"),
    first("secid").as("secid"),
    first("summary").as("summary"))
  .withColumn("summary",
    when(isMoreThanOne($"datelist", $"summary"), "more").otherwise($"summary"))
  .drop("datelist")
  .show()

//    output
//    +---+-----+--------+-----+-------+
//    | id|count|    date|secid|summary|
//    +---+-----+--------+-----+-------+
//    |  1|    9|20170608|    2|   more|
//    |  1|    8|20170608|    2| random|
//    |  3|    9|20160608|    3|  equal|
//    |  2|    8|20170608|    3|   less|
//    +---+-----+--------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for ur Reply i have used above code its working but only summary is "equal" only i need to group and change it as more

Comment: It got changed to `more` for id 1. Do you want value `more` for all the summary which is `equal`?

Comment: in input if u have id secid count date   summary
1   2     9    20170608  random
1   3     9    20160608  random  here id and count same but summary is "random" so we should not change. only summary which is "equal" only that rows only we need to check

Comment: id secid count date   summary
1   2     9    20170608  equal
1   3     9    20180208  equal   here this senario the second row should come 1   3     9    20180208  more, but its coming date with first record